# Как получить все одинаковые свойства с асоциативного массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть ассоциативный массив из которого нужно забрать все свойства name и запихнуть это в другой массив.
Получается взять только последнее.

Запись получается формата [1][2][3] , а нужно так [1,2,3]

Как это лучше всего делать?
Вот сам массив :

```
var json_date = [{
    "dills": {
        "1": {
            "name": "soccer",
            "time": "13:00",

        },
        "2": {
            "name": "football",
            "time": "15:00",

        },
        "3": {
            "name": "baseball",
            "time": "11:00",

        }
    }
}];
```

Вот мое решение . Но нужно ток сами свойства [soccer, football, baseball]

```
 var i;
var resedent = 0;
for (var i in json_date[0].dills) {
 resedent++;
var sten = []
sten[sten.length] = json_date[0].dills[resedent].name
  var calkulete = 0
     calkulete++;
    $('li > h1').text(sten[0]) 
   }
  console.log(json_date[0].dills[1])
```

Comment: А покажите ваше решение

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский добавил своё решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var json_date = [{
    "dills": {
        "1": {
            "name": "soccer",
            "time": "13:00",

        },
        "2": {
            "name": "football",
            "time": "15:00",

        },
        "3": {
            "name": "baseball",
            "time": "11:00",

        }
    }
}];

var obj   = [],
    json  = json_date[0].dills;

for(var i in json) {
    obj.push(json[i].name);
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: а как обратиться к полю `dills`, если не знаешь изначально его имени?

Answer (score 3):

Если не знаете название элементов, то так:

```
    var arr = [];

for(var mainEl in json_date[0]) {


  var objMainEl = json_date[0][mainEl];

  for(var el in objMainEl) {

    arr.push(objMainEl[el].name);
  }
}
```